# DmlException: Merge failed. First exception on row 0 with id first error: DELETE_FAILED

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage, developer, app-development

> Error: System.DmlException: Merge failed. First exception on row 0
>   with id  first error: DELETE_FAILED,TargetX_SRMb.ContactTrigger:
>   execution of AfterDelete caused by: System.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Trigger.TargetX_SRMb.ContactTrigger: line 188, column 1: []

Trigger.TargetX_SRMb.ContactTrigger is as part of Managed package that has been installed. In sandbox, I'm running the test class for the batch class in developer console using system Admin profile.

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an "After Delete" trigger and the line 188 is in the middle of a guessably somewhat bigger class, I'd say that the error arises from a line of code, that tries to access either a `Trigger.new` variable or a variable that holds the SObject Ids (which are gone in after delete context).